# How to get an instance of an activity from a fragment in Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a SignInActivity like this:

```
public class SignInActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> signIn());

        noAccountButton.setOnClickListener(v -> goToMainActivity());
    }

    private void signIn() {
        //Start auth process
    }
}
```

My app can be used with or without an account. In both situations the user is redirected to MainActivity. This activity holds a fragment where I display a message such if the users wants to become a user of the app though. I also have a button like this:

```
public class UserFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            instanceOfSingInActivity.signIn();
            //     ^      ^
        });
    }
}
```

And I need an instance of the SignInActivity so I can call the **signIn()** method. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `SignInActivity` the host for `UserFragment`? Or is `UserFragment` being shown in some other activity?

Comment: First of all, an activity shouldn't be doing logic like signing in. This violates SOLID principles. If you still want to do it like that, you can call getActivity() and cast it to SignInActivity given it is the host activity of the UserFragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare No, the MainActivity is the host for the UserFragment.

Comment: @m0skit0 The MainActivity is the host of the UserFragment and **not** the SignInActivity, that's the problem.

Comment: Then there may not even be an instance of `SignInActivity`. Your fragment certainly cannot get access to it. If your objective is to show `SignInActivity`, `UserFragment` can call `startActivity()`. If your goal is to reuse the `signIn()` method, then that code should reside somewhere outside of any activity or fragment.

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes, the goal is to reuse the signIn() method. In that case, I will move that method outside the activity. Thank you legend!